# How to create C (not C++) console application in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I was trying with VS2012 to do following:

File->New Project->Win 32 Console application.
Go to properties C/C++->advanced and set `Compile as C Code (/TC)`

Rename source files extension cpp->c (not sure it is needed)

But project is compiled like C++ anyway.

What else should be done to make project compile as `C`?

Comment: I've compiled C code in VS exactly like this. How are you checking it's compiling as C++?

Comment: For example according this error: Error 1 error C4996: 'strdup': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C++ conformant name: _strdup. See online help for details.

Comment: That doesn't have anything with C vs C++.

Comment: You seem to be under impression that `strdup` is a standard C function, which is somehow omitted from C++. This is not the case: `strdup` is not specified by either C or C++ standards.

Comment: Microsoft has divergent views on how POSIX should be supported.  Their insistence on a leading underscore for POSIX names is symptomatic of that divergent view.  POSIX reckons that if you request for POSIX functions (as you should do explicitly by specifying `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` for example), then you're entitled to get them.  Microsoft seems to think otherwise.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That rule isn't found in the C or C++ standards, is it?  Rules from an unsupported third-party API aren't binding on a library implementation that doesn't claim conformance to that API.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Section 4 Conformance of the C standard says: _A conforming implementation may have extensions (including
additional library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any strictly
conforming program._ referencing footnote 4 which says _This implies that a conforming implementation reserves no identifiers other than those explicitly
reserved in this International Standard._ POSIX works within that by requiring you to specify explicitly reserved identifiers like `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to indicate that you want extensions enabled. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ Many programs written for Linux assume that all the extensions will be available automatically.  In fact, that tends to be because the headers define `_GNU_SOURCE` (a reserved identifier) unless you suppress it, and this enables the extensions for POSIX (and GNU).  So, by using identifiers reserved to the implementation, POSIX source can indicate it wants extensions enabled.  AFAIK, though, Microsoft insists that even with those macros defined by POSIX as exposing/enabling the extension, the function names must start with `_`, thus making life painful for compliance.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Compliance is deprecated (transitioning from compliant to non-compliant).  During the transition, warnings are triggered to highlight the identifiers that will be removed when POSIX compliance is removed.  The OP has apparently enabled `/Wx` to convert all warnings to errors.

Comment: There also is a macro to disable the warnings.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235384.aspx

Comment: @BenVoigt: I view what MS requires as antithetical to what POSIX expects, and I believe that MS does not need to set up the hurdles for the reasons they state (but they do so for other reasons).  However, MS clearly doesn't agree, and mercifully, I don't have to care either way as I don't have to work on Windows any more or make code compatible with Windows any more — woohoo!  I don't plan to continue the discussion as sane people can disagree with my viewpoint, and while I think they're wrong, there's little point in continuing the discussion.

Answer (score 2):

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384838.aspx),

> By default, the Visual C++ compiler treats all files that end in .c as
>   C source code, and all files that end in .cpp as C++ source code. To
>   force the compiler to treat all files as C regardless of file name
>   extension, use the /Tc compiler option.

Also, [Compiling with ANSI C in Visual Studio](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~patt/13s.460N/labs/vstudio.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is compiling as C.

Not as C99 or C11 or C-plus-support-for-APIs-from-other-OSes.

Just plain ISO-standard-compliant C89/C90.  Which is what the C compiler shipped with VS2012 supports.

Comment: ..plus a bit of C99 :)

Comment: @icepack: I think that came after VS2012, didn't it?  Until recently Microsoft had a strict policy of freezing the C compiler at C89.  (Or maybe it depends on the `/Za` ANSI-compliance mode)

Comment: I think it had some features, such as inline functions and variadic macros, not so?

Comment: @icepack: [Variadic macros are in VS2012 for C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177415%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not sure about `/Tc`.  Maybe both use the exact same preprocessor.